# Trying to center this ordered list box. Easy simple HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

working on some solo projects. Trying to copy some very simple webpages - and I'm not sure how exactly to center this information that is in the ordered list class 'muskfacts'

Could someone please help me get this box centered?

HERE is an example of what the page currently looks like: [image: CURRENT PAGE]

HERE is an example of what I'd like the page to look like:
[image: DESIRED PAGE]
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
  <title>Tribute Project</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
  </head>


  <body>
  <header>
    <div class='title'>
      <h1>Elon Musk</h1>
    </div>

  <figure>
    <div class='elonimg'><img src='elon.svg' alt='Error Loading Image'></div>
    <figcaption><em>Comic Book Elon Musk</em></figcaption>
  </figure>
  </header>

  <article>
    <div class='elonfacts'>
      <h2>About The Legend</h2>

      <ol class='muskfacts'>
        <li>Elon Musk created and sold a video game to a magazine when he was 12
          years old. ‘Blastar,’ a space fighting game, was sold for $500 to PC
          and Office Technology magazine. Musk also worked for ‘Rocket Science,’
          a gaming start-up.</li>
          <br>
        <li>According to Ashlee Vance, author of Elon Musk: Tesla, SpaceX, and the
           Quest for a Fantastic Future, Musk almost sold Tesla to Google for $11
           billion in 2013. Tesla’s future looked bleak at the time, so Musk
           approached Larry Page, Google’s co-founder and CEO, for a takeover.
           Musk proposed that Google purchase Tesla for $6 billion, with Musk
           promising to invest another $5 billion in factory expansion. Musk also
           demanded that Page hand over control of Tesla to him for the next eight
           years. The deal came to a halt at the eleventh hour when the sales of
           Model S, an all-electric five-door liftback produced by Tesla, Inc
           began to pick up. Tesla is expected to be worth around $100 billion
           by 2020.</li>
          <br>
          <li>Musk’s first business venture was the founding of Zip2, a company
            that provided newspapers with maps and business directories and was
            later sold to Compaq for $307 million.</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
  </article>

  <footer>
    <p> For more information, check out <strong>Elon Musk</strong> on Wikipedia.</p>
    <address> Developed by <a href='mailto:jacob@foundingfatherscollective.com'>
      Jacob Tibi</a>
    </address>
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #00FA9A;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px
}

figure {
  display: inline;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 60px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: -50px;
  align-items: center;
}

article {
  background-color: rgb(46, 139, 87, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #98FB98;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  width: 750px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

ol {
  margin-top: -40px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.muskfacts {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-position: inside;
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 650px;
  height: 370px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  .page {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can using `margin` to do it

```
article{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Working code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #00FA9A;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px
}

article{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

figure {
  display: inline;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 60px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: -50px;
  align-items: center;
}

article {
  background-color: rgb(46, 139, 87, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #98FB98;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  width: 750px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

ol {
  margin-top: -40px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.muskfacts {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-position: inside;
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 650px;
  height: 370px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  .page {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
  <title>Tribute Project</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
  </head>


  <body>
  <header>
    <div class='title'>
      <h1>Elon Musk</h1>
    </div>

  <figure>
    <div class='elonimg'><img src='elon.svg' alt='Error Loading Image'></div>
    <figcaption><em>Comic Book Elon Musk</em></figcaption>
  </figure>
  </header>

  <article>
    <div class='elonfacts'>
      <h2>About The Legend</h2>

      <ol class='muskfacts'>
        <li>Elon Musk created and sold a video game to a magazine when he was 12
          years old. ‘Blastar,’ a space fighting game, was sold for $500 to PC
          and Office Technology magazine. Musk also worked for ‘Rocket Science,’
          a gaming start-up.</li>
          <br>
        <li>According to Ashlee Vance, author of Elon Musk: Tesla, SpaceX, and the
           Quest for a Fantastic Future, Musk almost sold Tesla to Google for $11
           billion in 2013. Tesla’s future looked bleak at the time, so Musk
           approached Larry Page, Google’s co-founder and CEO, for a takeover.
           Musk proposed that Google purchase Tesla for $6 billion, with Musk
           promising to invest another $5 billion in factory expansion. Musk also
           demanded that Page hand over control of Tesla to him for the next eight
           years. The deal came to a halt at the eleventh hour when the sales of
           Model S, an all-electric five-door liftback produced by Tesla, Inc
           began to pick up. Tesla is expected to be worth around $100 billion
           by 2020.</li>
          <br>
          <li>Musk’s first business venture was the founding of Zip2, a company
            that provided newspapers with maps and business directories and was
            later sold to Compaq for $307 million.</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
  </article>

  <footer>
    <p> For more information, check out <strong>Elon Musk</strong> on Wikipedia.</p>
    <address> Developed by <a href='mailto:jacob@foundingfatherscollective.com'>
      Jacob Tibi</a>
    </address>
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```